# sqlite is using wrong index in left join

Tags: sql, performance, sqlite, indexing

I am joining two tables with a left join:

The first table is quite simple

```
create table L (
  id integer primary key
);
```

and contains only a handful of records.

The second table is

```
create table R (
  L_id     null references L,
  k        text not null,
  v        text not null
);
```

and contains millions of records.

The following two indexes are on R:

```
create index R_ix_1 on R(L_id);
create index R_ix_2 on R(k);
```

This select statement, imho, selects the wrong index:

```
select
  L.id,
  R.v
from
  L left join 
  R on 
         L.id = R.L_id and
         R.k = 'foo';
```

A `explain query plan` tells me that the select statement uses the index `R_ix_2`, the execution of the select takes too much time. I believe the performance would be much
better if sqlite chose to use `R_ix_1` instead.

I tried also

```
select
  L.id,
  R.v
from
  L left join 
  R indexed by R_ix_1 on 
         L.id = R.L_id and
         R.k = 'foo';
```

but that gave me `Error: no query solution`.

Is there something I can do to make sqlite use the other index?

Comment: Are you sure that `r_ix_1` exists and contains what you think it does?

Comment: Yes, I confirmed with `.schema R` in the sqlite3 prompt.

Answer (score 2):

Your join condition relies on 2 columns, so your index should cover those 2 columns:

```
create index R_ix_1 on R(L_id, k);
```

If you do some other queries relying only on single column, you can keep old indexes, but you still need to have this double-column index as well:

```
create index R_ix_1 on R(L_id);
create index R_ix_2 on R(k);
create index R_ix_3 on R(L_id, k);
```

Comment: I am not 100% convinced. When I do `select * from R where k = "foo" and L_id = 42` the performance is blazingly fast, without the suggested index.

Comment: And have you tried to execute the original "join" query while having the double-column index created?

Comment: Not yet, I need to wait for the evening until I start create indexes.

Comment: I'm suggesting it, because it might be that SQLite picks up your single-column indexes when you use `SELECT ... WHERE`, but the planner might not be smart enough to combine those indexes when you  join tables. I don't know if that's the case, but it's possible. You will know it once you try it.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if the SQLite optimizer just gets confused in this case.  Does this work better?

```
select L.id, R.v
from L left join 
     R
     on L.id = R.L_id 
where R.k = 'foo' or R.k is NULL;
```

EDIT:

Of course, SQLite will only use an index if the types of the columns are the same.  The question doesn't specify the type of `l_id`.  If it is not the same as the type of the primary key, then the index (probably) will not be used.

Comment: No, unfortunatly - and `explain query plan` tells me that neither `r_ix_1` nor `r_ix_2` (nor any other index) is used.

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger . . . Do the two fields have *exactly* the same type?  That would be one reason why the index cannot be used.  (Your question omits the type in the first table.)

Comment: You mean if `L.id` has the same type as `R.L_id`? No, they're not the same, `R.L_id` is without type (as per `.schema`, if there is such a thing as typelessnes in sqlite) and  `R.L_id` is an `INT`, and you're a genious, as I believe that this difference is most likely the case. Let me change the datatype and test it again, but that can't be done today.

Comment: it was indeed the different types that caused the problem. With the same types it works perfectly (provided I epxlicitely state the `indexed by` clause). If you turn your comment into an answer, I will accept it as the solution.